# isset condition behaves different on different clicks

Tags: php, mysql, submit, isset

I am working on a page in which there is a list of 5 chapters quiz and each chapter has 3 set of buttons (Appear, Request, Requested) which appear based on certain database conditions. When a user first time appears for the quiz for a particular chapter the button present there is 'Appear'. Now if he attempts and fails in the Quiz for that chapter, the button turns to 'Request'(as the user now needs permission to reappear for the quiz from the admin). Now when he clicks on the 'Request' button it does a set of database operations and the next button appears is 'Requested'. This is working fine for all the chapters but only in case if the user has 'Requested' for the previous chapter and goes to attempt and request the immediate next chapter, the state of button stays to 'Request' only rather than 'Requested'. I am having no clue on this about why is this not changing its state from 'Request' to 'Requested' on submit. Following is my code, Please a help would be life-saver for me and highly appreciated.

```
    <?php include 'blocks/headerInc.php' ; ?>
<?php require_once "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";?>
<?php include 'blocks/leftnavInc.php' ; ?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 page-right">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading">Quiz Module
<button type="reset" onClick="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="btn btn-danger" style="    margin-left: 86%;margin-top: -30px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle" ></i> Go Back</button> 
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
     <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th>Module Name</th>
        <th>Total Attempt</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Pass Date</th>
        <th style="display:none;">Due Date</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Action</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
<tbody>
<?php
ob_start();
$created_on     =   $db->idToField("tbl_user", "created_on", $_SESSION['session_user_id']) ;
$sqlQuery       =   "SELECT * from tbl_question_module order by id ASC" ;
$sq             =   $db->query($sqlQuery);
if($db->affected_rows > 0)
{   
$i = 1;
$days_for_start =   ''; 
$days_for_end   =   '';

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sq))
    {
     extract($row);

$pass_fail_sql=mysql_query("select * from tbl_user_quiz_cleared where module_id='".$row['id']."' and chapter_id='0' and user_id='".$_SESSION['session_user_id']."'  order by id desc");
$pass_fail_data=mysql_fetch_array($pass_fail_sql);
$rows_count = mysql_num_rows($pass_fail_sql);
$clered=$pass_fail_data['cleared'];
if($clered=='1')
{
$date=$pass_fail_data['created'];
$dat=strtotime($date);              
$pass_date = date('d-m-Y', $dat);   
}
else
{
$pass_date='';
}
 if($fnc->getReattemptData($id,$_SESSION['session_user_id'], "days_for_start") !='')
 {
     $days_for_start    =   $fnc->getReattemptData($id, $_SESSION['session_user_id'], "days_for_start");
 }
 if($fnc->getReattemptData($id,$_SESSION['session_user_id'], "days_for_end") !='')
 {
     $days_for_end  =   $fnc->getReattemptData($id,$_SESSION['session_user_id'], "days_for_end"); 
 }
       $startDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on. ' + '.$days_for_start.' days'));
     $end_date  =   date("d-m-Y", strtotime($created_on. ' + '.$days_for_end.' days'));  

?>                
<tr>

    <td align="center"><?php echo $i ; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $title; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rows_count; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $startDate; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $pass_date; ?></td>

<td style="display:none;"><?php //echo $dueDate ; ?></td> 
   <?php 
     $pass_sql=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from  tbl_user_quiz_cleared where user_id='".$_SESSION['session_user_id']."' and module_id='$id' and cleared='1' and chapter_id='0'"));
   ?>

 <td align="center">
     <?php
        $crtDate    =   date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
        $crtDate    =   strtotime($crtDate);
        $today_date=date('Y-m-d');
        $user_sql=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from tbl_user where id='".$_SESSION['session_user_id']."'"));
        $glCorporateDay=$user_sql['request_updated_day'];
        $register_date=$user_sql['register_date'];
        $glDtRegister15=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ '.$glCorporateDay.' days', strtotime($register_date)) );
        $user_reattempt_sql=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from tbl_user_reattempt where user_id='".$_SESSION['session_user_id']."'"));    // Added by Anand to obtain 15days grace.
        $grace = $user_reattempt_sql['days_for_end']; // Added by Anand to obtain 15days grace.
        $grace_date= date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+ '.$grace.' days', strtotime($startDate)) ); // Added by Anand to obtain 15days grace.

       if( ($rep->checkUserAttemptQuiz($_SESSION['session_user_id'], $id) <=2 ) && ($pass_sql==true))
          { 
         ?> 
         <input name="" type="button"  value="Cleared" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">
          <?php 
          }
      if(($glDtRegister15==$today_date || $grace_date==$today_date  ) && ($pass_sql==false) )   
          {
         echo '<input name="" type="button"  value="Disable" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">';
          }
      else
          {
      if($rep->checkUserAttemptQuiz($_SESSION['session_user_id'], $id) < 2  && (strtotime($end_date) >= $crtDate) && (strtotime($startDate) <= $crtDate) && ($pass_sql==false) ) 
          { 
       ?><input name="" type="button" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='instructions.php?moduleId=<?php echo $fnc->encode($id) ; ?>';" value="Appear" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
                              <?php }else{
                            //

                                } ?>
                             <!--  <?php

                               ?> 
                            <input name="" type="button"  value="Overdue"  onClick="javascript:window.location.href='instructions.php?moduleId=<?php// echo $fnc->encode($id) ; ?>';" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
                                 <?php 
                               //  }
                                 ?> -->

     <!---3rd time  -->                           

                    <?php 

                     if(($rep->checkUserAttemptQuiz($_SESSION['session_user_id'], $id) == 2) && ($pass_sql==false ) )
                          { 

                          $module_get=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from module_quiz_request_user where request_attempt='3' and user_id='".$_SESSION['session_user_id']."' and module_id='$id'"));

                         ?> 

                      <form action= "moduleList.php" method="POST">
                        <?php  
                          if(($module_get['request_status']=='1')&&($module_get['quiz_status']=='1'))
                            {
                          ?>
                           <input name="" type="button"  value="Requested" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
                          <?php }
                          ?>
                          <?php  
                           if($module_get['request_status']=='2')
                           {
                           ?>
                          <input name="" type="button" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='instructions.php?moduleId=<?php echo $fnc->encode($id) ; ?>';" value="Appear" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
                          <?php }
                           ?>
                          <?php  
                              if(($module_get==false)) 
                                {
                           ?> 
                           <input name="request_3" type="submit"  value="Request" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
                           <input name="module_id" type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $id;?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"> 

                            </form>
                                               <?php }  ?>
                                               <?php } 
                                               ?>

    <?php 
}                      
    ?>

                </td>

                </tr>
<?php $i++; } } ?>               
              </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.sidebar-offcanvas-->
  </div>
</div>
<?php include 'blocks/footerInc.php' ; ?>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['request_3']))
 {
   $user_id=$_SESSION['session_user_id'];
   $module_id=$_POST['module_id'];
   $request_status='1';  
   $designation_get=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from tbl_user where id='$user_id'"));
   $designation=$designation_get['designation'];
   $salutation=$designation_get['salutation'];
   $user_register_date=$designation_get['register_date'];
   $corporate_id=$designation_get['created_by'];
   $request_updated_day=$designation_get['request_updated_day'];
   $level_designation=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from  tbl_level_email where attemp='3' and designation_id='$designation'"));
   $designation_email=$level_designation['designation_email'];
   $data = array("module_id"=>$module_id,"user_id"=>$user_id, "request_status"=>$request_status,"created_date"=>date('Y-m-d'),"request_attempt"=>"3","user_permission"=>$designation_email,"quiz_status"=>"1");
   $db->query_insert("module_quiz_request_user", $data);
}

?>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: `if (($module_get == false)) { /* ... */ <input name="request_3" type="submit" value="Request" class="/* ... */" />`
Maybe your `$module_get` is empty and therefore your query runs in an error? Have you debugged it?

Comment: Thanks for time. Yes I have debugged it. `if (($module_get == false)) { /* ... */ <input name="request_3" type="submit" value="Request" class="/* ... */" />` This only gets records once the request button is clicked and the database operations are done.

Comment: And this works absolutely fine for alternate chapters shown in a list. My concern is on submit at 'Request' the isset doesnot run if the earlier chapter in the list is in 'Requested' phase.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Is there something we can look upon?

Comment: Sorry, i got no clue so far.

Comment: Can there be any specific reason for the control not going to `if(isset($_POST['request_3']) && !empty($_POST['request_3'])) ` ?? Because if the form submit button is there and its clicked, the control must go to the `if(isset($_POST['request_3']) && !empty($_POST['request_3'])) ` This is what as far as I know in php.

Comment: First of all `isset()` and `!empty()` are redundant, because `empty()` checks for being `null` aswell. I'll look into that.

Comment: Earlier I was using `if(isset($_POST['request_3']))` . Now after getting this behaviour of code I changed it to `isset()` and `empty()` but still no luck.

Comment: Can you provide the UPDATE query for your script please?

Comment: BTW, you have a bracket error in your code, but that does not create the problem:
Move one of the closing brackets behinde the closing `</form>` tag above it.

Comment: `$data = array("module_id"=>$module_id,"user_id"=>$user_id, "request_status"=>$request_status,"created_date"=>date('Y-m-d'),"request_attempt"=>"3","user_permission"=>$designation_email,"quiz_status"=>"1");`
          $db->query_insert("module_quiz_request_user", $data);` Now this is the INSERT query that will produce the desired 'Requested' button.

Comment: Can you provide a database entry for a valid Accept, Request and Requested state?

Comment: you want entries for all three states?

Comment: Also based on your text, can you debug if the `$module_id` stores the correct module id upon inserting the new dataset?

Comment: Yes, i want one entry per state

Comment: For those chapters which are working fine, the `$module_id` is showing correct.

Comment: And for those who are not working fine? :-D

Comment: `Full texts  id  module_id  user_id  request_status 1-pending,2-confirm created_date  request_attempt  user_permission  quiz_status 0-request,1-requested,2-startquiz
 Edit Edit  Copy Copy  Delete Delete  54  1  886  1  2017-11-27  3  3,5  1` This entry causes the 'Requested' button visible. This shows, the user has taken 2 attempts and after clicking the 'Request' button this entry is made.

Comment: For those which are not working fine the control  after clicking 'Request' doesnt lands up isset()

Comment: Just added a screenshot of the entry.

Comment: And the request for the given entry shows **Request** instead of **Requested**?

Comment: This entry shows 'Requested'. As you can see it has module id 1. Now if I go for module 2 then after 'Request' clicking it should make a similar entry for module 2 and then 'Request' button converts to 'Requested' for module 2

Comment: Actually when clicking on 'Request', the control is not going to `isset()` to perform further db operations. But if i skip module 2 and go for module 3 then again the flow of buttons as well as db operations are performed in correct way.

Comment: But it does not? Right? What are the values for the INSERT in that case?
[Working code for oyur example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/605a20428ddf5951205181f05316442d750cce85)

Comment: Would you mind providing me your email ID? I can post you file in there so that things are more clearer for you. Only if you are comfortable.

Comment: Maybe your problem is, that after changing to the next chapter the POST values from the old chapter are still there. Try `unset($_POST['request_3']);` after your insert.

Comment: ok. let me try.

Comment: Sorry, no luck . :(

Comment: OK, here is what i think you should do:
I think the code you provided does not show the code, that seems to create the problem. You should provide the full part of moduleList.php that works with inserting the new rows to your table, aswell as the ones that update/delete your rows. It would also help alot if you could style your code correctly, so it is easier to read. Example: [php-sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c9db2ac040ab2f54393acb73faae56aa7d9f8209)

Comment: So where should I post the whole code?

Comment: Can we discuss over this? If you are okay

Comment: Well your insights will be highly valuable for me. @PhilippMaurer

Comment: Hey @Ansh, i saw your similar post on codereview, but i think its better here. Just replace the code you postet so far with the code that saves and updates the request data. (It should be moduleList.php)

Comment: Thanks for your concern .Please check the update. Posted the full code of moduleList.php @PhilippMaurer

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the appearance of the buttons. As you can see the alternate buttons are green and they are in 'Requested' state. The blue buttons are 'Request' buttons that are not getting into 'Requested' state. This is the pattern that is coming up. Although the database entries are just perfect for each of the modules listed and according to database entries they all should be in 'Requested' state. @PhilippMaurer

Comment: I can not find the line where `$id` is set. That would be very interesting. Also can you provide the generated HTML of the table?

Comment: `$id` is coming from header files. And i didn't get that 'HTML of the table'?? What exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes now finally sorted. A misplaced bracket and hence solved. :)